# "Placing" oil, but "placing" frankincense

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mincha-meal-offering, parashat-vayikra

When discussing the מנחת חוטא (the *mincha* form of the קרבן עולה ויורד), the Torah ([*Vayikra* 5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0305):11) instructs that

> לֹא יָשִׂים עָלֶיהָ שֶׁמֶן וְלֹא יִתֵּן עָלֶיהָ לְבֹנָה
>   he will not place on it oil, and he will not place on it *l'vona*

(frankincense, apparently). Why does it use ישים for oil and יתן for *l'vona*?

Comment: I've already checked _Rashi_, ibn Ezra, _Malbim_, and Rabbi Hirsch ad loc. to no avail. Also _M'nachos_ 59–60, which is _doresh_ this _pasuk_, does not answer this question AFAICT.

Comment: Just saw your comment after posting my answer. Why is Menachos 59b not helpful to you?

Comment: @Dave, because I missed that part of the _g'mara_! `:-(`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Menachos 59b-60a - שימה implies even a minimal amount, while נתינה is a kezayis.